# How to make a Flash player plugin using Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, flash-cs5, flash

This may sound silly, but I am trying to make a Flash player plugin using Visual C# 2008 language but I have no idea how to do it so can anybody give me some clues about it like tutorial websites/videos?

Comment: "make" as "create clone of Adobe Flash Player" or "render on HTML page" or "render in my Win Form/WPF/... application"?

Comment: How can i "make" as "create clone of Adobe Fplash Player"? Which software do i need to "make" it?

Answer (score 0):

I think below links help you:

- [Source 1](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/kfra/archive/2006/10/04/50003.aspx)
- [Source 2](http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-play-flash-swf-inside-c.html)
- [Source 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/flashexternalapi.aspx)
- [Source 4](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/FlashPlayerCustomControl12042006230129PM/FlashPlayerCustomControl.aspx)